# How do I get the bitrate from a WMA file in C#?

Tags: c#, wpf, bitrate, wma

I've searched using Google for any information that could help me accurately get bitrate data from a wma file.  As far as I can tell, there isn't any documentation on either obtaining the bitrate or on the layout of a wma file.  Does anyone have information on either the wma file format, or better, a code sample that will get the bitrate?

Thanks

Comment: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/tims/2004/03/28/extracting-metadata-from-windows-media-files/

Comment: That blog is 14 years old and none of the links that look interesting work.  A Google search for "MediaCatalog" or "MetadataEditor" wasn't very productive either. The only link that still works goes to "Windows Media Format SDK" which is an external library I'd prefer not to use.  I'm trying to put everything into a single exe, and adding a dll just to get the bit rate seems excessive.